# Spring app on Tomcat 7 problems

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

When I start my app localy with embeded tomcat 7 everything is working fine. But when I deploy to the remote machine with tomcat7:redeploy (maven plugin) I have problems with the part of the application. App starts fine and parts of it are working, but when I send XML package to the app it throws this exception :

```
 ERROR o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot process message
        at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:74)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:170)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.PollingConsumer.handleMessage(PollingConsumer.java:74)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:202)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:52)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:146)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:143)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:278)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:272)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot process message
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:78)
        at org.springframework.integration.transformer.AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer.java:64)
        at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:68)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot process message
        at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:284)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:142)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:75)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.xml.transform.TraxUtils.isStaxSource(Ljavax/xml/transform/Source;)Z
        at org.springframework.oxm.AbstractMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractMarshaller.java:124)
        at com.mozzartbet.joker.api.udp.UDPTransformer.transform(UDPTransformer.java:31)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:63)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:122)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:44)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:258)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:84)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:114)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:111)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:159)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:268)
        ... 26 more
```

Version of the java on both machines is the same 1.6.45, and there is only this webapp on the remote tomcat instance. I tried playing with the endorsed dir but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the root cause:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.xml.transform.TraxUtils.isStaxSource(Ljavax/xml/transform/Source;)Z
        at org.springframework.oxm.AbstractMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractMarshaller.java:124)
```

I'm guessing that there's a conflict between the Spring version of the JAR and the one that ships with Tomcat.  Tomcat's server class loader finds their version first and doesn't have the method that Spring needs.

Comment: I was thinking the same and that`s why I played with endorsed directory. javax/xml/transform/Source is interface, I looked which class implemented it and have put it`s jar in the endorsed dir. No success. Maybe I am doing it wrong? Can you suggest how to do it?

Comment: If you can find both JARs, try removing the offending one completely and replace it with the one that Spring wants.  You'll have to hope that Tomcat doesn't balk.